# Android - Best way to access Room Database Asynchronously

Tags: android, android-asynctask, intentservice, android-room

So I have a Room database with some Users stored in it. This is the current method im using to access the database and get data.

```
    User user;
    userDAO = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(getApplicationContext()).userDao();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            user = userDAO.getUser("testuser1");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String name = user.getName();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

My question is there a better way to do this. I'm doing all this in my Activity code and I'd like to clean it up.

How would you go around implementing something like a static or abstract class which has callbacks to the main thread/activity so I can listen for responses. I'm still new to asynchronous tasks, so apologies if im being stupid.

I also need to be able to access the database from my Service which is always running. Also I sometimes need to save some data when the OnDestroy() method is called, and if I run an thread from there, it results in an crash. Maybe something like a IntentService? But I need to be able to call different methods to get and save different objects.

Answer (score -2):

in AppDatabase class you have to use below code:

```
@Database(entities = {User.class},version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase
{
     public abstract  userDAO userDao();
}
```

in UserDAo class you have to use below codes:

```
@Query("select * from User where user =:search")
User getUser(String search);
```

for use these methods you can use below codes:

```
User user;
public static AppDatabase database=null;
if (database==null)
    {
        database= Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),AppDatabase.class,"nameOfDatabase")
                .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    }
user=database.userDao.getUser("testuser1");
```

Comment: you are querying the database on the main thread on the main thread which is antagonizing the question, Best way to access Room Database Asynchronously?